# How to disable cookies with Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Does anyone know if there's a way to disable cookie management in Spring WebClient using Reactor Netty HttpClient?

I noticed both [WebClient.Builder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder) and [HttpClient](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.java) APIs provide a means to add cookies to an outbound request but I am looking for a way to inhibit them altogether if such exists. That is akin to `disableCookieManagement` on Apache's [HttpComponentClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#disableCookieManagement()).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's no way to disable the cookie handling per se but this seems to work: Create your own HttpClient, then use HttpClient.doOnRequest to register a callback to be called before sending the request. In the callback, call HttpClientRequest.requestHeaders() to retrieve the request headers, then delete the `Cookie` header.

Sample code that removes `User-Agent` header before sending the request.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().doOnRequest((request, connection) -> {
           request.requestHeaders().remove("User-Agent");
        });
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
        Mono<String> r = client.get().uri("https://www.google.com").retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
        System.out.println(r.block());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code example for this? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: Yes, if you can wait a few hours, it’s at home!

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, I'm not seeing that Reactor Netty HttpClient is doing anything at all with the cookies that come back in the response. I was actually looking to enable a cookie store like the Apache HttpClient supports, but to all indications the Netty HttpClient has no such feature.

In the [entire codebase of Reactor Netty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/search?q=set-cookie&unscoped_q=set-cookie), there is no usage of the "set-cookie" header except in one of their unit tests. This tells me cookies are ignored by default unless the client code chooses to look for them.